# Stable alternative to Snagit for Mac

Tags: osx, screen-recording, screenshot

I'm having multiple issues when using SnagIt on Mac:

- Taking videos often freezes my computer
- Taking full-page screenshot does not work

Hence I am looking for a good alternative to SnagIt for Mac.

Here are my requirements:

- Takes fullscreen screenshots
- Takes "zone" screenshots: select a zone of the screen to take a pic of
- Takes "whole page" screenshot: must be able to take a screenshot of a whole page even if the page is longer than my screen's height
- Takes fullscreen screencasts
- Takes "zone" screencasts: select a zone of the screen to take a video recording of
- Rarely (if ever) crashes
- Under $100 if possible. Great if further info on the licensing model, i.e. some are yearly & others are a one time fee